# SKNode perform animation before removing

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I'm making a 2d side scroller.

There are rockets that spawn in from the right.

When I chuck a projectile at one, I want it to:

- act like it's been hit, perhaps move back slightly on its vector path, flash red, that sort of thing
- the projectile should stick into the rocket, like an arrow (node.position = RocketNode.position hasn't worked for me unfortunately :| )
- if the enemies HP is 0, perform a death animation
- after the death animation, remove the rocket and projectile

Below is the code i've been trying to get working, I'm confused about which node is which, and how to target the two different nodes... bodyA and bodyB perform the same thing is also pretty inefficient...

This all sits in the `didBeginContact` function... I've left in some commented code, warts n all.

```
 case projectileGroup | rocketgroup:
        if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == rocketgroup || contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == rocketgroup
        {



            //projectileObject.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVectorMake(0 , 0)

            if Model.sharedInstance.sound == true

            {
                runAction(RocketExplosionPreload)
            }

            Model.sharedInstance.totalscore = Model.sharedInstance.totalscore + Model.sharedInstance.score


            RocketExplodeTexturesArray = [SKTexture(imageNamed: "RocketExplode0"),SKTexture(imageNamed: "RocketExplode1"),SKTexture(imageNamed: "RocketExplode2"),SKTexture(imageNamed: "RocketExplode3"),SKTexture(imageNamed: "RocketExplode4"),SKTexture(imageNamed: "RocketExplode5"),SKTexture(imageNamed: "RocketExplode6")]

            let RocketExplodeAnimation = SKAction.animateWithTextures(RocketExplodeTexturesArray, timePerFrame: 0.1)

            let RocketExp = SKAction.repeatAction(RocketExplodeAnimation, count: 1)

            print(contact.bodyA.node)
            print(contact.bodyB.node)



            if let node = contact.bodyA.node as? SKSpriteNode {
                print(node)
                //node.paused = true
                if node.parent != nil {


                    let moveUp = SKAction.moveToY(0, duration: 1)

                    let fadeOut = RocketExp



                    let remove = SKAction.removeFromParent()

                    let moveAndFade = SKAction.group([moveUp, fadeOut])

                    let sequence = SKAction.sequence([moveUp,fadeOut])




                    RocketNode?.runAction(sequence) {
                        /// remove theSprite from it's parent
                        /// Might need to weakly reference self here
                        RocketNode!.removeFromParent()
                        ProjectileNode!.removeFromParent()
                        print("Deleted")
                    }






                    //node.removeFromParent()
                }
            }
            if let node = contact.bodyB.node as? SKSpriteNode {
                print(node)
                //node.paused = true
                if node.parent != nil {

                    let moveUp = SKAction.moveToY(0, duration: 1)

                    let fadeOut = RocketExp



                    let remove = SKAction.removeFromParent()

                    let moveAndFade = SKAction.group([moveUp, fadeOut])

                    let sequence = SKAction.sequence([moveUp,fadeOut])




                    RocketNode?.runAction(sequence) {
                        /// remove theSprite from it's parent
                        /// Might need to weakly reference self here
                        RocketNode!.removeFromParent()
                        ProjectileNode!.removeFromParent()
                        print("Deleted")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: I've made such a game where you have homing missiles and stuff like that. Still, I don't really get what is the problem? Try to concentrate on specific task. For example, the part where you remove the rocket and a projectile may be done with action sequences. The part with hit points can be done in such way that rocket has a method called applyDamage(damage) etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @whirlwind commented, you are asking a lot of questions at the same time here. 
I haven't run this code, but it should definitely point you in the right direction.

```
class RocketNode: SKSpriteNode
{
  var HP: Int = 10
  func runHitAnimation()
  {
    // flash red or something
  }
}
```

Detecting the contact:

```
let projectileCategory: UInt32 = 4 // some power of 2
let rocketCategory: UInt32 = 8

func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact)
{
  let firstBody = contact.bodyA
  let secondBody = contact.bodyB

  if (firstBody.categoryBitMask | secondBody.categoryBitMask) ==
    (projectileCategory | rocketCategory)
  {
    self.evaluateRocketProjectileContact(between: firstBody, and: secondBody)
  }
}
```

Evaluating the contact:

```
func evaluateRocketProjectileContact(between firstBody: SKPhysicsBody, and secondBody: SKPhysicsBody)
{
  var rocketBody: SKPhysicsBody
  var projectileBody: SKPhysicsBody

  if (firstBody.categoryBitMask & projectileCategory) > 0
  {
    projectileBody = firstBody
    rocketBody = secondBody
  }
  else
  {
    projectileBody = secondBody
    rocketBody = firstBody
  }

  let rocket = rocketBody.node as! RocketNode
  let projectile = projectileBody.node as! SKSpriteNode

  rocket.HP -= 1

  // move projectile to rocket and remove its physics body
  projectile.moveToParent(rocket)
  projectile.physicsBody = nil

  if rocket.HP == 0
  {
    // do something explosive animation
    let explode = SKAction.scaleBy(2.0, duration: 1.0)
    rocket.runAction(explode, completion: { 
      rocket.removeFromParent()
    })
  }
}
```